# Create table from cluster centroid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cluster-analysis, k-means

I've got an Oracle Data Mining question I'm struggling to find a solution with. I've used the kmeans clustering algorithm on a dataset i'm working with and everything works okay my data is  clustered well and i've named the clusters. My question is , is there a way to create a new table with just the ten clusters and their centroid values for each attribute?

So for example I would have Cluster 1 with the centroids for education,wealth,unemployment etc. The reason for wanting this extra table is so i can create graphs and charts comparing the clusters in excel or arcmap. ODM seems to have this facility as I can compare clusters but i cant export the values.

Thank you

And a picture of the clusters 
[Cluster Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DSzS.png)